# How to find the zeros of $f(x) = 2x(5-x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How do I get the zeros, if $f(x) = 2x(5-x)$.

I have told by my classmate that in order to get the zeros of $f(x) = 2x(5-x)$, I need to distribute $2x$ to $(5-x)$.

So I distribute it to make it $10x-2x^2$.

This is the part where I am stuck.

How can I solved for the zeros of it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'find the zeroes'? Do you mean 'find the *roots* '?

Comment: @mikhailcazi :  General usage is zeroes of a function and roots of an equation (polynomial)... so what he said does makes sense..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I didn't know that, so was clarifying. :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi : That is alright :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I would rather use solution for an equation. And by the way a polynomial and an equation are distinct objects.

Comment: @Taladris : I did not mean polynomial and equation are same objects...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: sorry, the parenthesis confused me.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Products of two factors is $0$ if at least one of them is $0$

Comment: you might want to add "can both of them be $0$ ??"

Answer (score 3):

Here the equation is $f(x) = 2x(5-x)$

We get the zeros' of a polynomial when we equate the function to $0$ 
thus in order to get zero's we should do the following

$f(x) = 2x(5-x)=0$

$\Leftrightarrow  2x(5-x)=0  $

i.e. $x=0 $ or $5-x=0$

thus we get zero's of polynomial as $x=0 $ and $x=5$

Note : The zero's of a polynomial $f(x)$ is the values of $x$ at which the function attains the value $0$ thus explains above answer.  and in $\mathbb{R}$ if product of two numbers is $0$ then atleast one of them must be equal to $0$